# R plotly, zoom on a choropleth map

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

In R using plotly i'm displaying the map of Asia using:

```
plot_ly (type = 'choropleth') %>% 
layout ( geo = list ( scope = 'asia' ))
```

Any idea how can I only display (I assume by zooming) the map of south east asia?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to let plotly automatically scale/zoom the map to display only a section with specific countries. But you can manually define the desired map section by using the `lonaxis` and `lataxis` layout parameters:

```
plot_ly(type = 'choropleth') %>% 
  layout(geo = list (scope = 'asia',
                     lonaxis = list(range = c(90, 150)),
                     lataxis = list(range = c(-15, 30))))
```

This produces the following map section which should cover Southeast Asia pretty well:
[image: Southeast Asia]

You might have to play around a little with those values to exactly meet your needs. According to the plotly reference [the values are set in degrees](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-geo-lataxis-range). But keep in mind that the appropriate values depend on the projection type set via [`layout(geo = list(projection = list(type = "..."))`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-geo-projection-type), so if you change the projection type, you'll probably have to adjust the `lonaxis` and `lataxis` ranges as well.

Furthermore you can zoom the map in and out by setting a value between `0` and `10` in [`layout(geo = list(projection = list(scale = ...))`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-geo-projection-scale).